# Unity3d, add component to prefab in resource

Tags: unity-game-engine

One time I was playing around with Resouce system in Unity I discovered this:

Say if you only load but do not Instantiate the prefab:

```
GameObject testObj = Resource.Load("testPrefab");
```

And you have a script called "`TestScript`", and you add this script to `testObj`

```
testObj.AddComponent<TestScript>();
```

You run it, and close it, this TestScript will still be inside `testPrefab` inside Resource folder, and if you run it again, the `testPrefab` in Resource folder will have two `TestScript` component.

I understand that `Resouce.Load()` is just point to that prefab in Resource folder, no copy has occured.

But would it be a good idea says, put a `CleanPrefab()` function in this prefab to make sure it restore to the original configuration first and then add other conponents as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not modify a prefab. Prefabs are made to be used as re-usable Objects. There are many reasons you shouldn't try to modify it. One of them is that it will affect instantiated objects references that prefab. With modifications done to your prefab, there is no guarantee your levels will start the way they are supposed to start. This will mess up your game.

> You run it, and close it, this TestScript will still be inside
>   testPrefab inside Resource folder, and if you run it again, the
>   testPrefab in Resource folder will have two TestScript component.

The behavior you described is only true in the Editor. One you build it, the behavior is totally different. In a standalone version, once you restart the program, the prefabs will automatically reset itself. What you are really modifying is the loaded prefab in the memory not the one stored on the disk. Also note that everything in the *Resources* folder is read-only. They can't be modified.

If you modify a prefab directly, it stays in the memory even when you reload the scene. The only time that modification will be gone is when you restart the application. Do not modify a prefab.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/30udy4/til_resourcesload_will_return_a_reference_not/), `Resources.Load` doesn't create a new instance of an object because it does not create an Object in the scene; that's what `Instantiate` does.

To avoid this problem of linking to the original prefab and avoid overriding, use `Instantiate()` and then add all your components with respect to that variable.

It is important to use `Instantiate` before apply new components to the object or modify the existing ones.

For instance you have this snippet of code:

```
void Start()
    {
        SelectCharacter();
        InstantiateObj();
        ControllerAssignment();
        AddColliderComponent();
        AddScriptComponent();
    }

private void InstantiateObj()
    {
        obj = Instantiate(obj_original_prefab); //apply changes to this variable
    }
```

This code is a correct implementation, where you call the `Instantiate` method before applying all the changes to the object `obj`, which is a 'deep copy' of your original prefab and not a reference!